# parse.com javascript display series of playing card images from single string

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform, playing-cards

my approaches aren't working.

I have users that can save random sequences of cards to the [parse.com] database. Now I want to display those cards as nice images.

An example of a sequence (string) from the database would be:
"7D7H7H7D7C7C7C7C7D7H"

I would like to use that string to display a series of images. In this case 20 images,

```
<img src="7D.jpg"><img src="7H.jpg"><img src="7H.jpg">
```

and so on, until all cards in that string are displayed.

I currently display the sequence from the parse.com database, it's just an ugly string for now.

```
query.find({
      success: function(results){
        var output = "";

        for (var i in results) {
          var sequence = results[i].get("Sequence");
          var id = results[i].id
          output += "<p>"+sequence+"</p>";
```

The 'output' is currently that string or 'sequence' example above.

Any help or ideas on how I can start displaying images is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of the card names 2 letters long?

if so, you can try creating a helper function outside of your code:

```
var cardRender = function(string) {
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i+= 2) {
    output += "<img src='" + string[i] + string[i+1] + ".jpg' >";
  }
  return output;
}
```

then call it in your original code:

```
query.find({
  success: function(results){
    var output = "";

    for (var i in results) {
      var sequence = results[i].get("Sequence");
      var id = results[i].id
      output += cardRender(sequence);
```

cardRender will return a string composed of a bunch of image elements. you can use it to create the result you want.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Yes, all cards are 2 letters long. The data is created with an iPhone app. It was an easy decision to use TD instead of 10D for just that reason. This looks so sweet on my page now!